# Very old novel about a planet with a living ocean

Tags: story-identification, novel, space

I read this novel more than 40 years ago, but I believe that it is much older than that, it was already a classic.

I don't remember much. There is a scientific station there, to study an ocean that seems to be alive (or, rather, that is definitely alive, but very mysterious). But I have forgotten all the details. Sorry to be unable to be more precise, but a very old classic about a planet with a living ocean, that might ring a bell?

Comment: @LogicDictates It did not take you long to guess it. And it did not take me much time, reading the summary on Wikipedia to recognise it.  Do post this as an answer  so I can accept it !

Comment: @Valorum Yes, indeed, a dupe ! But once more, it did not appear in the box suggesting previous questions that could be related.  Can it be formally a dupe before I have even accepted the answer ?

Comment: @Alfred - Yes, because your "*This is it!*" comment serves as an acceptance.

Comment: @LogicDictates - Meta question raised here about the timeline of events; https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/13993/reopening-a-closed-question-so-you-can-add-an-answer-then-reclosing-it